# Перенос БД с Windows (х86) на Windows (х64)

Tags: delphi, база-данных, firebird

У меня стоит Windows 8.1 (x64), и FireBird 2.5.4.26856_0 с помощью IBExpert 2015.6.17.1, при соединении с БД, ошибка:

```
«Connection authorization failure.  
file D:\....gdb is not a valid database»?
```

При запуске моего приложения, работающего с этой БД, также ошибка:

```
file D:\... .GDB is not a valid database.
```

Причем приложение которое работает с этой БД, отлично работает на
- Windows 8.1 (х86), и FireBird 2.5.4.26856,
- Windows ХР (х86), и FireBird 2.5.4.26856.

У меня есть еще 3 приложения с разными БД, 1 приложение работает, с другими тоже такая же ошибка.

Как её исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутренний формат хранения данных в firebird специфичен для платформы. Файл базы, созданный на x86, не будет валидным на x64, и наоборот.

Для корректной конвертации вам придётся сделать [backup](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/gbak.html) на x86, и restore на x64. Просто скопированы файл базы заставить работать не получится.

Вот аналогичный вопрос на enSO: [Statement failed, SQLSTATE = -922 my_database.gdb is not a valid database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9792513/1988244)

Comment: Я уже пробывал, бэкап БД создается, но в отчете по restore, ошибка "*…
gbak:restoring domain RDB$8 
IBE: Unsuccessful execution caused by system error that does not preclude successful execution of subsequent statements.
     Invalid metadata detected. Use -FIX_FSS_METADATA option.
     Malformed string.
     Exiting before completion due to errors.*"  - я в параметрах restore выставлял "charset", но это не помогло... Всегда (правда давно) делал эту операцию, а тут вот такое...

Comment: @Konstantin78 а опция -FIX_FSS_METADATA не помогает?

Comment: @Konstantin78 в любом случае - добавьте это в вопрос. Может быть кто-то другой сталкивался.

Comment: Спасибо, я устанавливал значения "WIN1251", НО ЗАБЫЛ ставить галочки.